# Wifi works when thethered from phone not directly

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, iwlwifi

My wifi is really fast when I access it via my Android smartphone's tether-able hotspot (80.5 Mbps download, 14.8 Mbps upload), but super slow when I access the wifi directly.

What might be the cause of this issue? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. There's a question mark in the wifi-spot for what it's worth.

Here's the Pastbin when I run the wireless-info script from https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info: https://pastebin.com/m3LsqXt5
Note that the `wireless-info` script was run using my tetherable-hotspot.

I ran tracepath www.google.com and sometimes it started with `1?: [LOCALHOST] pmtu 1500` and sometimes with `1?: [LOCALHOST] pmtu 1492`

Let me know if I can provide any more useful information.

Thanks!

Comment: Run the `wireless-info` script from https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

Comment: Run `wireless-info` again, connected to the slow wifi interface and `diff` the two outputs.

Comment: @waltinator, I tried but I guess there isn't enough bandwidth. I get `Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Connection timed out. wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’`